# Add option to a select and select it

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I have [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/tEUxg/)

```
var opt = $("select option:first");
opt.remove();

$("button").on("click", function() {
    $("select").prepend(opt).val(1);
});
```

That works fine in some browser. But, of course, IE isn't one of them. In IE the combo ends with the two options, but the text is in blank (there is no selected option). I assume this is because the option is still not loaded into the DOM. I assume that because I can easily fix this problem using [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/tEUxg/1/) instead:

```
var opt = $("select option:first");
opt.remove();

$("button").on("click", function() {
    $("select").prepend(opt);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("select").val(1);
    }, 1);
});
```

However, I would prefer something nicer. Any ideas?

*Note: I'm not looking for performance in the selector or things like that. The posted code is just a reduced example, not my real script.*

Comment: Does running `opt.prop("selected", true).prependTo("select");` work in IE? By the way, you may want `.detach()` instead of `.remove()` to keep data and events.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? It's somewhat surprising that that doesn't work if you're using an up-to-date version of the library.

Comment: @pointy It is surprising, but it fails as described with 1.8.2.  `prop` as @pimvdb suggested fails as well, though I swore it worked the first time I tried it but will not work again.

Comment: Your jsFiddle works fine for me in IE. Tested in IE7 and up.

Comment: @IHateLazy In IE9 for me, the select becomes unselected rather than selecting the number 1.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: Ah, I just had it in IE7 and 8. I see it now in IE9.

Comment: Works for me If I do `.val(1).val(1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work on all browsers, though I have no idea why your original code failed in IE.

```
var opt = $("select option:first");
opt.detach();

$("button").on("click", function() {
    $("select").prepend(opt).prop("selectedIndex", 0);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tEUxg/5/

Answer (score 2):

IE using queue system for DOM manipulation. Use `dequeue()`:
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N2UF4/)

```
var opt = $("select option:first");
opt.remove();

$("button").on("click", function() {
    $("select").prepend(opt).dequeue().val(1)
});
```

Comment: That is truly bizarre.  Do you happen to have any info on why this happens?  Maybe a jquery blog post or something?  This is the first I'm hearing of this.  I'm wondering if maybe this isn't exactly what is happening but rather something in `dequeue` is interrupting the process long enough to let the DOM update.

Comment: I think you could find it in MSHTML (trident) specification. Unfortunately, i dont have any relevant link to post.

Comment: As well as I can't understand it, I think its nicer @James way. However is really good to keep this in mind. +1!

Comment: @James Montagne: Turns out that it comes down to a simple accessor that's necessary on the select. If you add a dummy `.each(function() { this[0]; })` before the `.val(1)`, then it works.

Comment: I filed a bug since this is something jQuery could work around: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13032.

Comment: @pimvdb Are you sure it's just IE9? And what do you mean it comes down to a simple accessor? You might want to include the other things that have "worked" to "fix" this problem that we've come across in this SO question...and even link to this SO question.

Comment: @Ian: In IE9 with IE7/8 emulated I don't see the bug. With "accessor" I mean accessing `this[0]`. (I did link to this question.)

Comment: @pimvdb Sorry, don't know how I missed the link to this question. And good, wasn't sure if anyone tried the emulated IE7/8. And I knew what you meant by "accessor", but that doesn't necessarily fix it...it's just one of the "solutions". As we've found out, using `delay`, `dequeue`, or (any) type of animation seems to work, where I'm sure there are more possibilities. As the OP pointed out, all you have to do is use `setTimeout` with the smallest timeout and that works too...it almost seems to be a timing issue. And it's interesting that `append` works fine...

Comment: @Ian: I found that the accessor fix works because I hunted down the code path of `.dequeue`, where somewhere such an accessor is used. Both `.dequeue` and `.delay` do effectively the same thing here: they call `$.data`, which is where the "fix" occurs (through an accessor). Not sure why `setTimeout` works, but then again, it often fixes things.

Comment: @pimvdb Huh, interesting. Yeah, not sure about `setTimeout` then after that find of yours...

Answer (score 1):

It's silly, but another solution based off the original solution you were thinking to use is:

http://jsfiddle.net/N2UF4/1/

```
var opt = $("select option:first");
opt.remove();

$("button").on("click", function() {
    $("select").prepend(opt).delay(1).val(1);
});
```

Still not sure why this is necessary (or the `dequeue` from the other answer) but it seems to "fix" the problem as well.

Comment: This is all very strange.  It seems as though calling anything animation related is forcing a DOM update.  It seems you can put pretty much anything animation related in place of delay there and it works (fadeOut, etc.)

Comment: As well as I can't understand it, I think its nicer @James way. However, your way is nice and works. +1!

Comment: @Diego I agree James' way is better - it's the real way this operation should be completed.